# python sent result in new windows

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to send some result from my program to a different window, not into the console (at my command prompt in Windows). That is, I want to learn to make a GUI application when I have only ever made a non-gui command line "hello world" program ever before, in Python. Where do I start:

Here's a command line program:

```
      print 'I love python '   # output to standard console output
```

How do I put that message "I love python" in its own new window?

Comment: I translated your question into english for you. I hope you like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to learn [tkinter](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/).  There is a lot of work that goes into making a "GUI" application with windows you create yourself.

Instead of one line of code where you print something, you will have to make a window, and put things into those windows, and then react to the user clicking on things.

**Update** Until I edited your question (after you accepted this answer) I was not sure, so I guessed you were asking "how do I make my output go to a new window, not to the console where my print statement is going now".  That unclear question has now been removed and replaced by my own rewrite of your question. (People who want to see the original unreadable question should look at the edit history).

Comment: Yes Not a console , I want it a windows to receive result form main program .